# What's the use case and explanation of frequency-domain subsampling?

Tags: fft, sampling, downsampling

In my solution to a certain problem I use subsampling in the frequency domain. Amazingly, it produces good results. Is it really that awkward to see subsampling in frequency domain? What the consequences really are?

Comment: Decimation in one domain <=> aliasing in the other domain. Who said it was awkward to see?

Comment: Just me - due to my little knowledge I guess. So how about two pictures of different sizes and their fourier transforms - can I compare their spectrum downsampling the larger to match the smaller one? Of course the number of samples is equal to the pixel count... but what happens to the image then?